# returning array from fortran subroutine called from Julia

Tags: fortran, julia

I need to call this fortran subroutine from Julia:

```
SUBROUTINE f90sub(N, a, b)
    integer, intent(in) :: N
    real(8), intent(in) :: a
    real(8), dimension(N) :: b
    integer :: i
    do i = 1, N
        b(i) = a**i  ! just an example
    end do
END SUBROUTINE f90sub
```

The subroutine is contained in the file *f90lib.f90*, which I compile with:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC f90lib.f90 -o f90lib.so
```

If I try to call the subroutine from Julia as follows:

```
N = 4
a = 2.5 
b = zeros(Float64, N)
N_ref = Ref{Int}(N)
a_ref = Ref{Float64}(a)
b_ref = Ref{Array{Float64,1}}(b)
ccall( (:f90sub_, "./f90lib.so"), Cvoid, (Ref{Int},Ref{Float64},Ref{Array{Float64,1}}), N_ref, a_ref, b_ref)
```

I get a segfault when I access the value of b. What is the correct way to do that?

(There are several questions/answers and examples similar to this one on SO and elsewhere, but they all appear to be outdated. I am using Julia v.1.1.0. The Julia docs is very much focused on C, and the Fortran part is not so clear to me; I did not find any useful Fortran examples.)

Comment: `Ref{Array{Float64,1}` looks strange, I guess it should be `Ref{Float64}`? if so, try to pass `b` directly.

Comment: oh yes, that works! Thank you!